# What is the origin of the surname Fair?

Tags: surnames, czechoslovakia

William C Fair born about 1802 in Báb, Hlohovec, Nitriansky, Czechoslovakia. This could be my 3rd great grandfather.
It would be nice to be able to confirm at least if Fair was known to be a surname in Czechoslovakia.
Anyone else have Fair as a surname in their tree that traces back to Czechoslovakia?

Comment: I have only very basic knowledge of Czech/Slovak, but neither William nor Fair appear to be Czech/Slovak names to me. William would probably be spelled Vilém. Do you know other spelling variants of that surname? Did you find immigration information or passenger manifests for this person? If the names got anglicized, we have to learn about the original names.

Comment: A much more important detail: Czechoslovakia did not exist until after World War I. The places you mentioned are in present day Slovakia. In 1802, the region was part of the Kingdom of Hungary (as far as I understand).

Comment: There's another daughter (Theresia) in 1792 (https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:V1WY-4G9). Whatever the rest of the name, the last letter is clearly an 'x', not an 'r' or 't'. And as others have pointed out, these people lived a century before Czechoslovakia was invented. The place is (Kis-)Báb, Nyitra, Hungary.